# Saxon-HE 9.9.1.5 stylesheet parameters not being set

Tags: c#, saxon, xslt-3.0

Building a .NET VSTO application using Saxon-HE 9.9.1.5. Setting global stylesheet parameters for the XSLT 3.0 transformer is not working. I am passing a Dictionary of QName / XdmAtomicValue to no avail.

The same XSLT works fine using Saxon-HE 9.8.0-10 in Java 8.

```
    private Dictionary<QName, XdmValue> createParameters(IDictionary<string, string> properties)
    {
        Dictionary<QName, XdmValue> retVal = new Dictionary<QName, XdmValue>(properties.Count);
        foreach (var kvp in properties)
        {
            LOGGER.Debug(String.Format("\tName: \"{0}\"; Value: \"{1}\"", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
            retVal.Add(new QName(kvp.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(kvp.Value) );
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public void Transform(FileInfo xmlInput, FileInfo output, IDictionary<string,string> properties )
    {
        try
        {
          Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
          stopwatch.Start();

          Xslt30Transformer transformer = Executable.Load30();
          Serializer serializer = processor.NewSerializer();

          FileStream outStream = new FileStream(output.FullName.ToString(), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
          serializer.SetOutputStream(outStream);

          FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(xmlInput.FullName.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
          Dictionary<QName, XdmValue> parameters = createParameters(properties);
          LOGGER.Debug(String.Format("\nInput: \"{0}\"\nOutput: \"{1}\"\nParameters: {2}", xmlInput.FullName, output.FullName, parameters.Count));
          transformer.SetStylesheetParameters(parameters);
          transformer.ApplyTemplates(inputStream, serializer);
          outStream.Flush();
          outStream.Close();
          inputStream.Close();
          stopwatch.Stop();
          LOGGER.Debug(String.Format("Generate model call took: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        }
        catch ( Exception e)
        {
            LOGGER.Warn(String.Format("{0} {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
        }
    }
}
```

Global XSLT defaults are being used in place of passed parameters

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the problem with

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Processor processor = new Processor();

            string xslt = @"<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='3.0' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' exclude-result-prefixes='#all'>
  <xsl:param name='p1' as='xs:string'>p1 default</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name='p2' as='xs:string'>p2 default</xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match='/' name='xsl:initial-template'>
     <xsl:value-of select='$p1, $p2'/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>";

            XsltExecutable xsltExecutable;

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xslt))
            {
                xsltExecutable = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(sr);

            }

            Xslt30Transformer xslt30Transformer = xsltExecutable.Load30();

            xslt30Transformer.CallTemplate(null, processor.NewSerializer(Console.Out));

            Console.WriteLine();

            xslt30Transformer = xsltExecutable.Load30();

            xslt30Transformer.SetStylesheetParameters(new Dictionary<QName, XdmValue>() { { new QName("p2"), new XdmAtomicValue("p2 new value") } });

            xslt30Transformer.CallTemplate(null, processor.NewSerializer(Console.Out));

            Console.WriteLine();

            XdmNode inputNode;

            string xml = @"<root><values></values></root>";

            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();

            docBuilder.BaseUri = new Uri("from:string-input");

            using (StringReader inputReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                inputNode = docBuilder.Build(inputReader);
            }

            xslt = @"<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='3.0' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' exclude-result-prefixes='#all'>
  <xsl:param name='p1' as='xs:string'>p1 default</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name='p2' as='xs:string'>p2 default</xsl:param>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match='shallow-copy'/>
  <xsl:template match='values'>
     <xsl:value-of select='$p1, $p2'/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>";

            XsltExecutable xsltExecutable2;

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xslt))
            {
                xsltExecutable2 = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(sr);
            }

            Xslt30Transformer xslt30Transformer2 = xsltExecutable2.Load30();

            xslt30Transformer2.ApplyTemplates(inputNode, processor.NewSerializer(Console.Out));

            Console.WriteLine();

            xslt30Transformer2 = xsltExecutable2.Load30();

            xslt30Transformer2.SetStylesheetParameters(new Dictionary<QName, XdmValue>() { { new QName("p2"), new XdmAtomicValue("p2 new value") } });

            xslt30Transformer2.ApplyTemplates(inputNode, processor.NewSerializer(Console.Out));

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

but the output I get with Saxon 9.9.1.5 is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>p1 default p2 default
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>p1 default p2 new value
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>p1 default p2 default</root>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>p1 default p2 new value</root>
```

Consider to  provide minimal samples of XML, XSLT and C# with the output you get to allow us to identify where the problem is.